# Visual Studio 2012 debug tests keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2010 there were keyboard shortcuts to debug all tests, debug tests in context and more.

For reference, in VS 2010 the chords were:

- Debug: All Tests in Solution: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- Debug: All tests in context: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

VS2010 also had keyboard commands to just Run All Tests

In VS 2012 I found the keyboard command for run all tests, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> but can't find a keyboard command for debug all tests, which I found to be a really useful command.

Am I being dense and missing it? Did they remove the keyboard shortcut? I haven't found much information searching with Google or Bing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like they are in Tools --> Options --> Keyboard with no ShortCut Assigned. It looks like the combinations that you used to use are still available.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the keyboard shortcuts were removed in VS2012. Using your answer I was able to go back and map the commands (which didn't have any shortcuts) to the old combos from VS2010

Comment: Can't edit my comment so I'm adding this. Additional note: The command I wanted from VS2010 that works was actually not DebugAllTestsInSolution but TestExplorer.DebugAllTests. For whatever reason the DebugAllTestsInSolution command keeps throwing a message "... (DebugAllTestsInSolution) which is not currently available." The other one works.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have the `TestExplorer.DebugAllTests` set to `Ctrl+D, A` ...

And I'm pretty convinced that I've not set that up, but not sure where it came from or whether it's a standard VS 2012 keyboard shortcut