# Keyboard shortcut for debugging the LAST test run in Visual Studio IDE (2013)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I know there are several [VS keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693324/visual-studio-2012-debug-tests-keyboard-shortcut) for running unit tests, but the one I really can't find and would like is to be able to run the last executed test in debug mode.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> will repeat the last run, but not in debug mode.

If you are debugging a test, and it changes context to the code you are actually running, and then you stop the test, is there a way to start that test in debug mode again using just the keyboard?

Answer (score 9):

I wanted the same thing.

Based on the technique found in the following post

[Visual Studio 2012 debug tests keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693324/visual-studio-2012-debug-tests-keyboard-shortcut)

I searched for TestExplorer.DebugSelectedTests and assigned a shortcut key to it.

At least in VS2015 (and hopefully in VS 2013) even while debugging changes context to the code you are actually running. The test remains selected in the test explorer window. So, you can run your shortcut key combo and the test will debug again.

Hope this solves the problem for you too.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question was for Visual Studio 2013, but got google go me here.

In Visual Studio 2019 is a shortcut for that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Control R, D is unfortunately frequently not working for me in VS 2022, version 17.1.1. Sometimes it does work. I can't figure out what determines whether or not it will work.

Comment: this has changed and is now Ctrl+; ,Ctrl+L on Linux

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ReSharper, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to rerun a test in Debug mode.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html